# ARKit - Extend the reach of "hitTest"

Tags: ios, swift3, scenekit, hittest, arkit

I want to perform a hit testing from a point on the screen to a Cube in a 3D world. I've been using `hitTest` from ARKit. It works when I'm standing close to the cube, but when I start moving backwards, it stops working. I'm assuming this is because it's locked to the camera's `zRange`.

I've tried to set the `clipToZRange` option to false, like so:

```
let hits = self.sceneView.hitTest(loc, options: [SCNHitTestOption.clipToZRange: false])`
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Am I not setting the option right, or is this a bug?

I am using the latest Xcode and iOS betas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the showFeaturePoints debug option from ARKit interferes with hitTest...

Comment: After some further testing, it seems like showFeaturePoints breaks a whole lot of things. Object tracking is very jittery when the feature points are turned on, but when they are off the objects are rock-solid.

Comment: this is especially true if you are hitTesting for .featurePoint eg `let hitResults = sceneView.hitTest(touch, types: .featurePoint)`... but when filtering for `.existingPlaneUsingExtent` for example, I did experience jittery tracking, but observed few if no interference problems with hitTesting...